# ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c' in Keras

Tags: python, keras, importerror

import error occurs when I try to import keras. I have no problem with Tensorflow and it works well on my laptop. I deleted the directory Keras installed and reinstalled that but error still occurs. And I tried with lower version of python but error still occurs.

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/yym30/PycharmProjects/Neurofiling/csv_practice/keras_prtc.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.datasets import mnist
  File "C:\Users\yym30\Anaconda3\envs\Neurofiler\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\yym30\Anaconda3\envs\Neurofiler\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
  File "C:\Users\yym30\Anaconda3\envs\Neurofiler\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..layers.merge import concatenate
  File "C:\Users\yym30\Anaconda3\envs\Neurofiler\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..engine.base_layer import Layer
  File "C:\Users\yym30\Anaconda3\envs\Neurofiler\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .training import Model
  File "C:\Users\yym30\Anaconda3\envs\Neurofiler\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import training_arrays
  File "C:\Users\yym30\Anaconda3\envs\Neurofiler\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse
  File "C:\Users\yym30\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
  File "C:\Users\yym30\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _ccallback_c
ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'
```

Here is the full error message.

Comment: Upgrade/reinstall scipy

Comment: This worked for me; installing scipy

Answer (score -1):

'_ccallback_c' is either being called from the wrong location, spelled wrong, or not in the directory.